# How to backup PhpStorm project Context?

Tags: phpstorm

I like so much the `Context` feature of `PhpStorm`, localized in `Tools` > `Tasks & Contexts` > `Save Context` or `Load Context`

When I have a new computer, I can import all `PhpStorm` settings, but how to can I backup `Context` to my other computer?

Comment: Not 100% sure but this folder (I'm on Windows 7 using PhpStorm v10) seems to be relevant: `C:\Users\USERNAME\.WebIde100\config\tasks`. For another OS/IDE version see https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206827437-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs

Comment: great! this is working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such data is stored in separate `.zip` files on per project basis (tasks and contexts separately -- 2 files per project).

On Windows 7 for PhpStorm v10 they will be located in `C:\Users\USERNAME\.WebIde100\config\tasks` folder.

For another OS/IDE version please check [this document](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206827437-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs).